# How can I continue a stuck update/install of virtualbox-ext-pack on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, virtualbox, dpkg

Recently, I was trying to update vbox-ext-pack on Debian, and it got stuck. It showed the license agreement and did not continue.

I have looked at the solutions mentioned [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860744), but none were satisfactory.

How can I continue the installation without killing dpkg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `htop`, `ps`, or a similar tool to find the PID of the vboxmanage process which is a child of dpkg.
2. Run the following command to enter a `y` into the process' stdin:

   `echo "y" | sudo tee /proc/PID_OF_VBOXMANAGE/fd/0`

   This works because the 0<sup>th</sup> file descriptor represents the stdin for the process. The `sudo tee` is needed because the vboxmanage process is running as a child of dpkg, which is running as root.

The installation should continue with a message like: `License accepted. For batch installation add
--accept-license=b674970f720eb020ad18926a9268607089cc1703908696d24a04aa870f34c8e8
to the VBoxManage command line.`.

This worked for me on Debian sid while updating to `virtualbox-ext-pack (5.1.30-1)` as of October 17, 2017.